# Extract a sub string from a string using regular expression

Tags: java, regex

Given the following Java codes:

```
String test = "'abc,ab,123',,,'123,aa,abc',,,";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("('\\w\\S+\')");
Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
boolean s = m.matches();
System.out.println(s);
```

I want to extract all the content in `''`, for example I want `'abc,ab,123'` and `'123,aa,abc'`. Why the outout is:

```
false
```

My regular expression is like: "find a `'`,followed by a number or a letter, followed by several non-space characters,followed by another `'`". It should have a match, what's wrong?

Comment: matches method tries to match the whole string. If you want to extract some text, you could use find function.

Comment: Then what should I use?

Comment: Use `m.find` instead of `m.matches`.

Comment: Also, you could have found this in the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html).

Comment: Use this `'[^']*'` regex to get the output you want.

Comment: What's wrong with the previous one?

Comment: `\\S` would also match `'`

Comment: but it `\\s` is followed by `\\w` which is a number or a letter

Comment: it's not small letter `s`, it's capital `S`, ie, `\\s` matches any space characters but this `\\S` would do the opposite of `\\s`, that is, it would match any non-space character not only letters or numbers.`'\\w\\S+'` Matches the  `'` then the word character following `'` then again it greedily matches any non-space characters upto the last `'` . To not to match greedily, you must define the pattern as ``'\\w\\S+?'`` . See your regex http://regex101.com/r/gL8sJ4/1 and the modified form of your's http://regex101.com/r/gL8sJ4/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Matcher.matches` will try to check if regex can match entire string (see the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29)). Since your regex expects `'` at the end, but your string last character is `,` matches returns false.
If you want to print one or more part of string which matches your regex you need to use [Matcher.find](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()) method first to let regex engine localize this matching substring. To get next matching substring you can call `find` again from the same Matcher. To get all matching substrings call `find` until it returns `false` as response.

Try:

```
String test = "'abc,ab,123',,,'123,aa,abc',,,";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("'[^']*'");//extract non overlapping string between single quotes
Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
while (m.find()) { //does the pattern exists in input (sub)string
  System.out.println(m.group());//print string that matches pattern
}
```

Comment: Good enough if full string verification is not required and single quotes are always present, so +1

Comment: Good job. So you explained a problem. Now to improve your answer even farther you can also describe solution you used. Remember that good answer contains (1) explanation of problem, (2) solution, (3) explanation of solution (even short one will do, remember that you are not posting answer only for OP but also for future readers).

Comment: @Liquid If you used it with `matches` then it fails because last character in string is not `'` but `,`. If you used it with `find` then it should match `'abc,ab,123',,,'123,aa,abc'` part because `.*` represents zero-or-more (`*`) of any-character (`.`) and because `*` is [greedy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html). You could try to make `*` reluctant by adding `?` after it, so try with `"'\\w.*?'"` (BTW you don't need to add ``\`` before `'`).

Comment: @almasshaikh I added some explanation to your answer. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: Thanks @Pshemo. It would be helpful for other's who might face same issue and would find it useful.